# Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit and MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 is supported for sharepoint 2013 server?

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are going to install sharepoint 2013 Server,In our system we are having environment in WS 2008 R2 standard  and 64 bit and MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2.

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit and MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 is supported   For sharepoint 2013 Environment.Is there any issues.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

The minimum software requirements for a stand-alone SharePoint 2013 installation is:

> - The 64-bit edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1
> - The 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Standard,    Enterprise, or Datacenter

Reference: [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx)

Comment: hi benny i refered this link if we install sharepoint 2013 with MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 there is no issues.

Comment: @elina As you see in my answer, SQL Server is mentioned

Comment: @elina That's why it says **minimum** requirements

Comment: just conform me Benny without any issues we can install SP 2013.. In this environment.(SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit.)

Comment: @elina Service Pack 1 is a lower version than Service Pack 2, meaning that any Service Pack greater than or equal to Service Pack 1 on SQL Server 2008 R2 is perfectly valid for installing SharePoint Server 2013. In other words: you're good to go ahead with installation.